# Parse json string using json.net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a string like the following in C#. I tried with JSON.NET but couldn't figure out how to retrieve the value.

```
"{[{'Name':'AAA','Age':'22','Job':'PPP'},
{'Name':'BBB','Age':'25','Job':'QQQ'},
{'Name':'CCC','Age':'38','Job':'RRR'}]}";
```

I would like

```
foreach (user in users){
   Messagebox.show(user.Name,user.Age)
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the library or tried anything yourself? There are a dozen or so tutorials online that should be able to help you get started.

Comment: Note: My code sample below removes the extra braces (present in the question text) that surround the array.  they cause the deserialize operation to fail.

Comment: @M.Babcock Yes.I try to use Dataset in json.net but there is no root in my json string.I google examples them always with root.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a code sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var text = @"[{'Name':'AAA','Age':'22','Job':'PPP'},
                    {'Name':'BBB','Age':'25','Job':'QQQ'},
                    {'Name':'CCC','Age':'38','Job':'RRR'}]";

        dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            dynamic item = data[i];
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Age: {1}", (string)item.Name, (string)item.Age);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I downloaded Json.Net through NuGet, but otherwise this is a standard .NET 4.0 Console App